# How to reposition a button when in focus?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a series of left-aligned buttons in a stack panel.  I'd like to make the currently selected button to be repositioned, preferrably have his alignment changed to right.

I have a style section in the resource xaml that define widht, height, alignment, etc. of all the buttons in the panel.

What whould be the best approach to accomplish the above?  Is it possible to change the style (i.e. change alignment from left to right) on the currently selected (clicked-on) button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `Trigger` on the `IsFocused` property and change the settings you need

Example:

```
<Button Width="50" Height="30" >
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```